# Javascript resizing with window.open and WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, wpf, browser, iwebbrowser2

I'm using WPF WebBrowser control and handling NewWindow3 events using following code:

```
IServiceProvider serviceProvider = (IServiceProvider)webBrowser.Document;
Guid serviceGuid = SID_SWebBrowserApp;
Guid iid = typeof(SHDocVw.WebBrowser).GUID;
SHDocVw.WebBrowser wb = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser)serviceProvider.QueryService(ref serviceGuid, ref iid);
wb.NewWindow3 += new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_NewWindow3EventHandler(wb_NewWindow3);
```

How to handle javascript resizing when navigating using window.open, something like this:

```
window.open('Sample.htm',null,'height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no');
```

Is there anyway to get height and width requested by caller in NewWindow3 event handler?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can save the values in your [INewWindowManager::EvaluateNewWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775416(VS.85).aspx) implementation and use the values later. An example can be found at http://code.google.com/p/csexwb2/source/browse/trunk/cEXWB.cs

Comment: Could you explain please. I'm not using C++

Comment: IE's API is COM, which is language-independent. You can use any COM-aware language to call IE's API. For meaning of APIs, refer to IE SDK documentation.